# Extract URL and title of webpage

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

When the user clicks a button on my Google Chrome extension when he's navigating a certain URL, I would like the extension to send the URL as well as the title (as specified in the HTML `<title>` tag) of the page to the server. Is there a way to get the URL and title of the current page (that the user is at)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`chrome.tabs.getCurrent()`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-getCurrent) to get the current tab. Then you can get the title and URL from the [Tab object](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#type-Tab), which will be passed to the callback:

```
chrome.tabs.getCurrent(function (tab) {
  var title = tab.title;
  var url = tab.url;
  // now you can send these data to your server via XmlHttpRequest
});
```